# React.js Redux reducer does not insert the item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm very new to React.js and Redux.

I'm trying to build a **very simple** shopping cart application.

[image]

What I want is if you hit on an item (*eg :- banana*) It should appear in the cart.

**(It should change the state of the cartReducer.js)**

But instead of pushing the item to the reducer state it pushes something else.

[image]

What is the reason for this error?

This is my code.

**cartReducer**

```
import {ADD_TO_CART} from '../actions/index'

const initialState =[

]

export default (state = initialState,action)=>{
  console.log("ACTION PAYLOAD",action.payload)
  switch(action.type){
    case ADD_TO_CART:
    return[...state,action.payload]
    default:
    return state
  }
}
```

**Item component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {addToCart} from '../../actions/index'

export class Etem extends Component {
  showItems = () => {
    const { items, addToCartAction } = this.props;
    console.log("ITEMS", items);
    return items.map(items => <div key={items.id} onClick={addToCartAction}>{items.name}</div>);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Items</h1>
        <div>{this.showItems()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// export default items;

const mapStateToProps = reduxState => ({
  items: reduxState.items
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addToCartAction: item => dispatch(addToCart(item))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Etem);
```

**Action**

```
export const ADD_TO_CART = 'ADD_TO_CART';

export const addToCart=(item) =>{
    console.log("ITEMMMMMMMMMM",item)
    return(
        {

            type:ADD_TO_CART,
            payload:item,
        }  
    )
}
```

Comment: can you show your combineReducers ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<div key={items.id} onClick={addToCartAction}>` this will pass the click event to `addToCartAction` instead of `item`.

Try this:

```
return items.map(item => (
  <div key={item.id} onClick={() => addToCartAction(item)}>
    {item.name}
  </div>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = reduxState => ({
  items: reduxState.cartReducer.items
})
```